ASP.NET Core Web API receive request body containing IFormFile but all properties are null from Angular
I am trying to send a request body which is an object from Angular to ASP.NET Core Web API. All the properties are showing null except ID.
Web API:
public class Book
{
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string? ISBNNo { get; set; }
    public string? BookName { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public string? AuthorName { get; set; }
    public string? BookImage { get; set; }
    public string? OperationMode { get; set; }
    public IFormFile? FormFile { get; set; }
}


In Angular, this is my class:

Component:
postdata(angBook: any) {
  if (this.angBook.valid) {
    const UIFormData: Book = this.angBook.value;
    const formFileData = new FormData();
    if (!UIFormData.BookID) {
      UIFormData.OperationMode = "ADD";
      UIFormData.BookID = 0;      
    } else {
      UIFormData.OperationMode = "EDIT";
    }

    if (this.file) {
      formFileData.append("file", this.file, this.file.name);
      UIFormData.FormFile = formFileData;              
      UIFormData.BookImage= this.file.name;
    }
    this.dataService.ObjBookAddModify(UIFormData);
  }
}

Angular service:
/**** To send Data to DB through Object */
public ObjBookAddModify(BookParameter: Book) {
  var headers = new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Accept": "application/json"
  });
  
  this.httpClient.post<any>(this.baseUrl + '/Books', JSON.stringify(BookParameter),{
    headers: headers})
    .subscribe();
}

The ASP.NET Core controller object shows all properties null except BookID (0).

Request Payload in Network:
{
  "BookID": 0, 
  "ISBNNo": "ISBN 0-091-96234-1", 
  "BookName": "You Become What You think", 
  "AuthorName": "Shubham Kumar Singh", 
  "Price": "23", 
  "BookImage": "galaxyInterio2.jpg", 
  "OperationMode": "ADD", 
  "FormFile":  {}
}

What am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Can you include the posted json please? In the browser just open devtools (f12) open the network tab, do the post request and copy the payload

Request Payload: {"BookID":0,"ISBNNo":"ISBN 0-091-96234-1","BookName":"You Become What You think","AuthorName":"Shubham Kumar Singh","Price":"23","BookImage":"galaxyInterio2.jpg","OperationMode":"ADD","FormFile":{}}

Request Header: Accept:
application/json
Content-Type:
application/json; charset=UTF-8
Referer:
http://localhost:4200/
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Google Chrome";v="123", "Not:A-Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="123"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"Windows"
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

Try replacing [FromForm] with [FromBody]

Its throwing Exception in Console. WebApi method did not hit.  {
"headers": {
"normalizedNames": {},
"lazyUpdate": null,
"headers": {}
},
"status": 0,
"statusText": "Unknown Error",
"url": "http://localhost:5159/api/Books",
"ok": false,
"name": "HttpErrorResponse",
"message": "Http failure response for http://localhost:5159/api/Books: 0 Unknown Error",
"error": {
"isTrusted": true
}
}

You are not posting the form data correctly to your API. As currently you are sending the request body as JSON ("Content-Type": "application/json") but your API expects the request with "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data".
postdata(angBook: any) {
  if (this.angBook.valid) {
    const UIFormData: Book = this.angBook.value;

     if (!UIFormData.BookID) {
       UIFormData.OperationMode = "ADD";
       UIFormData.BookID = 0;      
     } else {
       UIFormData.OperationMode = "EDIT"
     }

     if (this.file) {
       UIFormData.FormFile = this.file;              
       UIFormData.BookImage = this.file.name;
     }

     this.dataService.ObjBookAddModify(UIFormData);
  }
}

With below, the HTTP request will be sent with "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" as default.
public ObjBookAddModify(BookParameter: Book) {
  let formData = new FormData();

  for (k in BookParameter) {
    formData.append(k, BookParameter[k]);
  }
  
  this.httpClient.post<any>(this.baseUrl + '/Books', formData)
    .subscribe();
}

